# How to export a virtual machine in Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, export

i am trying to export a virtual machine in Hyper-V.

i click `Export`, i select a location:

[image]

and click `Export`, and nothing happens:

[image]

How do you export a virtual machine in Windows Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears (judging from the 'e$' in the screenshot) you're trying it from a client workstation using the Hyper-V Manager.  Try logging into the virtual host and exporting it to a drive that is local to that host machine.

Unfortunately if this does work, it does not explain why what you are doing isn't working. I was able to verify the ability to successfully export a VM from a Windows Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V server using Hyper-V Manager installed on another machine.

Comment: i also tried it locally (i thought about screenshoting those steps, and eliminiate any question). i am going to blame it on the fact that we had recently deleted 4 or 5 intermediate snapshots, and hyper-v was busy doing that instead. i presume that if we wait long enough the export will appear (but it *has* been about 45 minutes and still nothin).

Comment: ah, you've solved your own mystery.  that was my next question: did you delete any snapshots recently?  If you've only just shut down the machine after deleting the snapshots, it can take an EXTREMELY long time (hours...days?) for the AVHD to merge with the VHD.  Most importantly, do not interrupt that process.  If you'd like to see the Merge progress, issue the following PowerShell command: Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\virtualization" -Query "select * from Msvm_ConcreteJob" | Where {$_.ElementName -eq 'Merge in Progress'}

Comment: We hadn't shutdown the VM; but had deleted snapshots. i presume the snapshot deletion happens as soon as you ask, but can, as you say, take days.